How to pre-load heavy scss layout styling in app router (Next.js 13-14)?
In my Next.js 14 app router project, I have to do some useEffect (client) works in my layout.
Because new layout.tsx is server side rendered, I created a RootLayout.tsx component and added "use client" attribute to achieve my goals.
Then I called this RootLayout inside my real layout which is empty server rendered one.
As you see in the image, even my server side rendered page is rendered but layout styling is not applied yet.
What is best practice for this kind of work? Putting this kind of works in layout is wrong?
during load
after fully loaded
The layout which app router provided
export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
      <meta
        name="viewport"
        content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1"
      />
      <body>
        <SessionProvider session={session}>
          <ClientLayout>
            <main>{children}</main>
          </ClientLayout>
        </SessionProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

Part of the my custom layout that I call in real layout

"use client";
import { ReactNode, useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import jwt, { JwtPayload } from "jsonwebtoken";
import { ConfigProvider, theme } from "antd";
import locale from "antd/lib/locale/tr_TR";
import { localStorageHelper } from "@/helpers/localstorage-helper";
import { useLayoutStore } from "@/store/layout/layout-store";
import { authService } from "@/services/authentication.service";
import { antComponentGlobals, antTheme } from "@/styles/_antd-theme.js";
import { ISession } from "@/types/base/next-auth";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import { Sidebar } from "@/components/layouts/sidebar/Sidebar";
import BreadCrumb from "@/components/layouts/breadcrumb/Breadcrumb";
import styles from "@/styles/Layout.module.scss"; 
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import "dayjs/locale/tr";


export default function ClientLayout({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {...

I imported my SCSS module in the layout that app router provided but it did not work.
What is the correct way?
